# invalid write of size 4 when assigning sum to a matrix

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision, valgrind

Hello I am trying to implement a 2d ryconvolution and I believe all my calculations and for loops are correct. However when I try assign sum to copy_output.at(y,x) I get a error write of size 
4 error when I debug with valgrind.
I have checked everything that could cause this. I have also initialized copy_output.

Valgrind error:

```
 Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==30604==  Access not within mapped region at address 0x10
==30604==    at 0x413594: algorithms::manual_filter_2d(cv::Mat const&, cv::Mat&, cv::Mat const&) (algorithms.cpp:137)
```

code:

```
void algorithms::manual_filter_2d(const Mat &input, Mat &output, const Mat &kernel) {

    int top;
    int bottom;
    top =  round(kernel.cols/2);
    bottom = top;
    int left;
    int right;
    left =  round(kernel.rows/2);
    right = left;

    Mat copy_output;
    Mat copy_input(input.rows,input.cols,input.type());
   cv::copyMakeBorder(input, copy_input, top, bottom,left,right, cv::BORDER_REPLICATE);

    for(int y=round(kernel.rows/2); y<copy_input.rows-round(kernel.rows/2); y++)
    {

        for(int x=round(kernel.cols/2); x<copy_input.cols-round(kernel.cols/2); x++)
        {
            float sum = 0.0f;
            for(int ky=0;ky<kernel.rows;ky++)
            {

                for(int kx=0;kx<kernel.cols;kx++)
                {

                  sum +=    input.at<float>(y+ky-((kernel.rows-1)/2) , x+kx-((kernel.cols-1)/2))*kernel.at<float>(ky,kx);


                }

            }
            copy_output.at<float>(y,x) = sum;  //line 137 that causes the segfault
        }

    }
    copy_output.copyTo(output);
    // TODO put your code here

}
```

Comment: Can you highlight line 137 in your code

Comment: @LonesomeParadise sorry I have edited my code highlighted the part that causes the segfault.  It's `copy_output.at<float>(y,x) = sum;` this line

Comment: Typo: `for(int x=round(kernel.cols/2); y<copy_input.cols` --> `for(int x=round(kernel.cols/2); ` **x** `<copy_input.cols` ?

Comment: You've default constructed `copy_output` but haven't given it any size information.  Will `at` change the size, or will it return a bad address?

Comment: @G.M. yeah I messed up when I was copying the code it was a typo but the problem is still there

Comment: You need to initialize `copy_output` to the size of the boundary-extended input, or you need to initialize it to the size of the input but write to `x-kernel.cols/2, y-kernel.rows/2`.

Comment: Also, `ky-((kernel.rows-1)/2)` makes no sense, remove the `-1` there, you don't use it elsewhere either. Is the kernel even or odd in size? For even-sized kernels your code might read out of bounds.

Comment: I need to use `ky-((kernel.rows-1)/2)` it's part of a formula required for the calculation. @CrisLuengo. The kernel is an even-sized-kernel

Comment: I don't understand where I should write the value  `x-kernel.cols/2, y-kernel.rows/2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have " Mat copy_output;" it is constructing Mat using default constructor which probably has 0 row and 0 cols.  When you call copy_output.at(y,x) = sum . It is trying to put at memory which is not there.

```
Mat copy_output(input.rows,input.cols,input.type());
```

or something similar to above.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have tried this and in addition of getting an invalid write of size 4 in the line mentioned , I now also get an invalid read of size 4 at `sum += input.at<float>(y+ky-((kernel.rows-1)/2) , x+kx-((kernel.cols-1)/2))*kernel.at<float>(ky,kx);`

Answer (score 0):

The code is designed for odd-sized kernel, and will not work without big modifications for even-sized kernels. This is likely the reason for your out-of-bounds reads. I recommend that you make your kernel odd-sized by adding a row and/or column of zeros as necessary.

Your out-of-bounds writes happen because `copy_output` is not the same size as `copy_input`. Assuming you initialized it as indicated in the other answer (`Mat copy_output(input.rows,input.cols,input.type())`, then

```
copy_output.at<float>(y,x) = sum;
```

writes out of bounds because `x` and `y` become larger than `input.rows` and `input.cols`. Either initialize `copy_output` to the size of the padded input image (the result of `cv::copyMakeBorder`), or write to:

```
copy_output.at<float>(y-kernel.rows/2,x-kernel.cols/2) = sum;
```

---

Note that `round` in your code is superfluous, `kernel.rows/2` is an integer division, yielding an integer number. `round` does nothing on an integer.